# How to update date in table to current date + 30

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update the date value in my table to 30 days the current date. I've tried using the DATEADD() function, but I seem to be doing something wrong because it is not working.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
$db->query("UPDATE properties SET renewal = DATEADD(dd, 30, GETDATE()) WHERE `id` = '$id'");
```

Comment: Your code is SQL Server code.  Why is the question tagged MySQL?

Comment: for MySQL its `DATE_ADD`

Comment: Side note: If your `id` column is integer, you don't need to surround the value with quote. By the way, your SQL statement is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: @Raptor you can't really say that with out knowing the source of $id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct MySQL syntax is:

```
UPDATE properties
    SET renewal = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 day)
    WHERE `id` = '$id';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
$newDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days"));
UPDATE properties
SET renewal = $newDate
WHERE `id` = '$id';
```